# Does the Pi have a get command?

Tags: curl

Some installation instructions require me to get a file from the Internet [using get](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_GET.htm)
but I can't find it on my Pi. Is it installable somehow, or is there an alternative I can use?

I am trying to get [iPlayer on the Pi](http://kimondo.co.uk/raspberry-pi-xbmc-media-server-completely/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`wget` will probably do the job. Alternatively use `curl`

Comment: I agree, use `wget http://passion-xbmc.org/addons/Download.php/plugin.program.repo.installer/plugin.program.repo.installer-1.0.5.zip`

Comment: Seems like the `lwp-request` command your describe is part of the `libwww-perl` package. You could install it using `sudo apt-get install libwww-perl`. But I'd just stick with wget, as it is already pre-installed, doesn't require perl, and is easier to use (as far as I can see).